# Configure Coveralls on both rspec and Grunt Karma tests

Tags: rspec, gruntjs, karma-runner, coveralls

I'm working with a project where we have both rspec tests covering the Ruby code, and we have set up Karma JavaScript unit tests run through a Grunt task.

I have set up [grunt-karma-coveralls](https://github.com/mattjmorrison/grunt-karma-coveralls) and can get it to generate a local coveralls.json when running `grunt test` and `dryRun: true`.  However I'm not sure how to configure my Coveralls repo_token.

I also have a .coveralls.yml which is successfully sending the report for the rspec tests to coveralls.

I am uncertain if, and how we can send both the coverage report for rspec and the grunt-karma report to Coveralls.

- I can try and set the COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN as an ENV variable before running `grunt test`, but would prefer to include it in the config somewhere
- It's fine with me if the reports display separately on Coveralls and are not merged.  I'd actually like to have separate coverage information for Ruby and JavaScript
- We are using Codeship as our CI

#### Update

- I now have a rake task that is setting the repo token, does all the npm and package setup, and runs the grunt test task.
- I also am successfully sending two separate reports to coveralls
- I'd still like to know if anyone has successfully merged coverage reports for a JS suite and a Ruby suite on Coveralls.
- I think I may be able to do some Simplecov hackery, and use the Coveralls push rake to push a single merged report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked, but I combine two JavaScript reports and send to coveralls. If you have the coverage report in `lcov` format it should not matter whether it is Ruby or Javascript.

This is for travis, but I imagine codeship would be similar.

```
cat ./coverage/lcov.info ./coverage/karma/**/*.info > lcov.info 
node node_modules/lcov-filter/index.js lcov.info config | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js && rm -rf ./coverage
```